# Do the codex pages give you XP, like they did in DA:O?

Tags: dragon-age-2

In Dragon Age:Origins, whenever you found a codex page you would get XP. You knew this because the amount you earned would appear in the corner of the screen, much like it does when you disarm a trap or open a chest in DA2. My question is, even though you don't see any XP shown when you find a page, I have noticed characters level up after finding one, so does this mean I am getting XP?

Comment: If you have seen characters level up immediately after reading, then I would definitely assume that you are getting the XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried this.  Yes, you do get experience.  I took note of my character's xp bar in the character screen and I received 50xp for getting a codex item.